# Who came first? IBAction or ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a Button on First VC which is directed to two active states.

1) `SecondVC`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    subjectPickerView.dataSource = self
    subjectPickerView.delegate = self
    SwiftyRequest()
    // Used the text from the First View Controller to set the label
}

func SwiftyRequest(){
    print("SecondViewController METHOD BEGINS")
    let jsonobj = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PostData")
    let json = JSON(jsonobj as Any)
        for i in 0 ..< json.count{
            let arrayValue = json[i]["name"].stringValue
            print(arrayValue)
            self.subjects.append(arrayValue)
            self.subjectPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    print(self.subjects)
}
```

2) `IBAction` of `FirstVC`

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost/AIT/attempt3.php",method: .post, parameters: ["something": semValue, "branch" : streamValue])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result)

            if let JSON1 = response.result.value {
                print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON1)")
               // JSONData.someData = JSON1 as AnyObject?
               UserDefaults.standard.set(JSON1, forKey: "PostData")
               UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
            else {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }

    }
}
```

NOW, Whenever i pressed the button it calls the `viewDidLoad` of `SecondVC` before `IBAction` of `FirstVC` which is a bit problematic for my app! How can i decide the priority between these two function.

Comment: have you linked it in `Storyboard`? Always viewDidLoad method called first. as it is life cycle VC

Comment: The main reason for the *delay* is the asynchronous behavior of `Alamofire` requests. Anyway you are strongly discouraged from using `UserDefaults` to pass data between controllers

Comment: You shouldn't be focusing on the order in which these functions get called. You should write them in way that makes it *not matter* in which order they are called

Comment: 1) Your question makes no sense. What does pressing the button in `FirstVC` have to do with `SecondVC`? There is no code in `buttonPressed` that creates or loads `SecondVC`. 2) Do not use `UserDefaults` to store data. That is not its purpose. 3) Do not needlessly call `synchronize`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about what you want to happen. Clearly the Alamofire call is going to take some time. What do you want to do with the 2nd VC while that time elapses? What do you want to do if the call does not return at all?

This is a common problem when dependent on external resources. How do you manage the UI? Do you present the UI in a partial state? Do you put a popover saying something like "loading". Or do you wait for the resource to complete before presenting the 2nd VC at all?

We cannot make that decision for you, since it depends on your requirement. There are ways to implement each one, though. If the resource usually responds quickly you could show the VC in a partial state and then populate it on some kind of callback. Typically call backs are either (1) blocks (2) delegate methods or (3) notifications. There is also (less commonly) (4) KVO. You should probably research the pros and cons of each.